# How should I open a PostgreSQL dump file and add actual data to it?

Tags: postgresql, file-io, csv

I have a pretty basic database.  I need to drop a good size users list into the db. I have the dump file, need to convert it to a .pg file and then somehow load this data into it.

The data I need to add are in CSV format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you already have a .pg file, which I assume is a database dump in the "custom" format.

PostgreSQL can [load data in CSV format using the `COPY` statement](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html). So the absolute simplest thing to do is just add your data to the database this way.

If you really must edit your dump, and the file is in the "custom" format, there is unfortunately no way to edit the file manually. However, you can use `pg_restore` to create a plain SQL backup from the custom format and edit that instead. `pg_restore` with no `-d` argument will generate an SQL script for insertion.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Daniel, the simplest solution is to keep your data in CSV format and just import into into Postgres as is.

If you're trying to to merge this CSV data into a 3rd party Postgres dump file, then you'll need to first convert the data into SQL insert statements.

One possible unix solution:

```
awk -F, '{printf "INSERT INTO TABLE my_tab (\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\");\n",$1,$2,$3}' data.csv
```